# 'remote-htpps' is not a git command

Tags: git-push

При попытке выполнить через командную строку:

`git push -u origin master`

Выдаёт ошибку:

> git 'remote-htpps' is not a git command. See 'git --help' The most similar command is remote-https

Я как бы и понимаю, что там должно быть `remote-https` вместо `remote-htpps`, но понятия не имею, как это исправить.

- Версия Git 2.18.0
- Версия curl 7.61.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, решения не нашёл. Пришлось прибегнуть к переустановке Git. Установлена была та же версия. Проблема решилась